# Recurring numbers by certain yomim tovim?

Tags: sources-mekorot, number, yom-tov

Does anyone know of any sources that talk about how each yom tov seems to have a special number attached? A number that seems to crop up several times?

For example:

**Rosh Hashana - 3**

3 sets of 3 shofar blasts, 3 different notes, three sections to shemoneh esrei (malchuyos, zichronos & shofaros)

**Yom Kippur - 5**

5 tefillos, 5 inuyim ("afflictions" - eating, drinking, washing or anointing the body, wearing leather shoes, and marital relations - see [Mishnah Yoma 8:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.8.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi)), 5 entrances into the Kodesh Hakodoshim.

**Succos - 7**

7 days ([Vayikra 23:42](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.23.42?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)), 7 ushpizin, 7 hoshanos, 7 items that make up the [arba minim bundle](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sukkah.3.4?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi) (1 lulalv + 1 esrog + 3 hadassim + 2 aravos).

**Pesach - 4**

4 cups ([SA OC 472:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.472.8?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), [4 sons](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_The_Four_Sons.1-2?lang=bi), [4 questions](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Magid%2C_Four_Questions.2?vhe=Pesach_Haggadah&lang=bi), [4 expressions of freedom](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.6.6-7?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

**Shavuos - 2**

[2 luchos](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.9.15?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0) (split into two categories - bein adam lemakom and bein adam lechaveiro), shtei halechem, 2 se'irim, 2 dibros said by Hashem.

Comment: Some of these are connected. Like 4 expressions of freedom and 4 cups of wine. 7 days and 7 ushpizin since there’s one per day.

Comment: Hi @Chatzkel - yes I am aware of that but I wondered if any mekoros speak actually about the significance of recurring numbers by different yomim tovim

Comment: Here's a shiur that discusses the 4s of Pesach. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BdBeR1-LIQ&ab_channel=RabbiManisFriedman

Comment: I also just saw that 5 on Yom Kippur corresponds to the 5 levels of the neshama, and this is relevant because atonement is achieved by revealing the core essence of the nefesh elokis, which is so pure that even sin cannot defile it. There are no numbered footnotes, just a collection of sources which I've screenshoted for you here: https://imgur.com/gHjNXe5